# Unable to create compound wildcard indexes

Tags: mongodb

On Mongo 7.0.0 installed via [homebrew](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#installing-mongodb-7.0-edition-edition), I'm attempting to create a compound wildcard index, copied from the [Mongo documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/core/indexes/index-types/index-wildcard/index-wildcard-compound/#use-a-helper-method-to-create-a-wildcard-index), but am getting a `wildcard indexes do not allow compounding` error message.

```
> db.salesData.createIndex(
   { tenantId: 1, "customFields.$**": 1 },
   {
      name: "tenant_customFields"
   }
)
MongoServerError: Error in specification { key: { tenantId: 1, customFields.$**: 1 }, name: "tenant_customFields" } :: caused by :: wildcard indexes do not allow compounding
```

Compound wildcard index should be available in Mongo 7.0, so perhaps I'm missing something? `db.version()` in my Mongo shell confirms that I'm on 7.0.0.

Comment: Hate to be that person, but your command runs fine on my machine...  `> db.version()
7.0.0` and `> db.salesData.getIndexes()[1]
{
  v: 2,
  key: { tenantId: 1, 'customFields.$**': 1 },
  name: 'tenant_customFields'
}` You didn't upgrade the binaries by chance? Also when you say 'Mongo shell' - you are referring to `mongosh` rather than legacy `mongo` (which was removed in `6.0`)?